# "request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" when making REST call to Jira

Tags: javascript, rest, jira, confluence, jira-rest-api

I'm using HTML macros in confluence to automate some tasks in Jira. I tried the following REST call in the code below to add a comment to a ticket and I get the error: **400: Bad Request. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**

I can't see any issues with my JSON or code. This pretty much fails for other operations I've tried such as creating/updating tickets.

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://<CONFLUENCEURL>.com:8090/plugins/servlet/applinks/proxy?appId=<APPID>&path=http://<JIRAURL>:8080/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-3/comment";
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }else{
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}   
var parameters = {
    "body" : "Hello world!"
};

function addComment() {
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(parameters));
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: I am finding myself in a similar problem, where my code / json looks perfect (I've replicated the REST call to be called from C#, everything is identical, except the order of properties - But I didn't think that mattered ... Perhaps I am incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually created an identically ordered JSON object, turns out that the parser the server side uses does not follow the JSON specification in that it expects the correct order.

As in, the fix would be to follow the JSON specification server side, or replicate identically the structures being sent to the server.